# In which "dimension" lives chrome.storage data in Chrome extensions (manifest v3)?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, google-chrome-storage

I developed a chrome extension, and it uses `chrome.storage` to save some (small) amount of information.

In my PC, it works fine, both as unpacked extension in dev environment and when download from Chrome Web Store as a regular user. Although, one of the end users reported the storage-related functionalities don't work in his PC (both running Windows, mine is Windows 11 and hers is Windows 10, same version of Google Chrome).

Somehow, her PC can't connect to the `chrome.storage`. **Her PC is in a big corporation intranet, subject to a proxy which can block communication with some sites.**

When I tried to use `localStorage`, I know where I can find the information in Chrome Dev Tools Application tab (in the respective application, because the content script uses the websites' `localStorage`, while the popup and service worker use their own, and none of them see ech other, unless I resort to message passing).

`Chrome.storage` API was a nice way to avoid message-passing, but for some reason it is not working in the end user PC.

For the worse, I can't have a proper debug, because, unlike `localStorage` info (which I access in the respective chrome dev tools Application tab), I can't find `chrome.storage` info.

Where is chrome.storage info stored, and where can I view it? Is it online? If so, which would be the domain to be cleared in the proxy, so it would work?